# Mysql: Selecting 4 entries in a table unique 2 and 2 dependent on row content

Tags: mysql

Lets say i have the following data:

```
ID        Name       Type
1         Uranus     Planet
2         Neptune    Planet
3         Earth      Planet
4         Titan      Moon
5         Callisto   Moon
6         Io         Moon
7         Moon       Moon
8         Content    NULL
9         Test       Only one of this
```

In total i always need 4 rows by randomly first select two equal types and then select two other equal not the same. It can’t select NULL or a type with only one row like “Only one of this type”.

Currently i do this by first getting the id of a unique planet by randomly selecting with HAVING COUNT(x) >= 2 and using this id in another select (the datatype can be different in other tables thats why i use the id and not the content of the type).

The reason i am not using only one select is that sub query’s are run for each row. Meaning since its selected randomly i could get a Planet and Moon in the first two rows.
To select the remaining two rows i do the same and make sure the type is different.

How do i optimise this? I have been looking into join and union but i can’t seem to get it to work. Should i change to a newer version of MariaDB which support sub-query’s that are run only once?

Example responces

Query 1: Uranus(Planet), Earth(Planet), Callisto(Moon), Io(Moon)

Query 2: Moon(Moon), Titan(Moon), Neptune(Planet), Earth(Planet)

Query 3: Neptune(Planet), Uranus(Planet), Io(Moon), Titan(Moon)

Comment: Where is your initial query?

Comment: I can give you the initial query but its actually 4 query's:

1. Select the id for the first two rows
2. Use the id to select two rows
3. Select the id for the remaining two rows different from the first id content
4. Use the second id to select two rows

Comment: You will need to provide examples: Show us the `results` of the 4 queries.

Comment: Example query for getting first ID: SELECT id FROM planets WHERE type IS NOT NULL GROUP BY type HAVING COUNT(x) >= 2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

Comment: Are there (4*3*2)*(3*2) = 144 legitimate combinations?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.name,'(',a.type,')') object_a
     , CONCAT(b.name,'(',b.type,')') object_b
     , CONCAT(c.name,'(',c.type,')') object_c
     , CONCAT(d.name,'(',d.type,')') object_d
  FROM solar_system a
  JOIN solar_system b
    ON b.id <> a.id
   AND b.type = a.type
  JOIN solar_system c
    ON c.type <> b.type
  JOIN solar_system d
    ON d.type = c.type
   AND c.id <> d.id
 ORDER 
    BY RAND() LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: It works but is over 10x slower than my current solution. Could i have have wrong indexes? Besides this i changed the select to LIMIT 1 since i only need four at a time not four, four times.

Comment: I don't know what your current solution is (although Id be pretty amazed if 2 queries were faster than 1). That said, using (My)SQL is never going to be brilliant for combinatorial problems. That said, where you're just dealing with 4! combinations, it shouldn't be too bad. I assume id is a PK, in which case `type` is the only other thing to index.

Comment: The type is already indexed as BTREE. Right now it takes 10-20x the time using this method then my initial setup.